# Почему палач - мастер "заплечных дел"?

Tags: фразеология

Можно было бы предположить, что это как-то связано с тем, что он рубит головы, но голова, вроде как, на плечах, а не за плечами. Почему же тогда - заплечных?
Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Палач  не  только  головы  рубил,  но  и  кнутом  полосовал  при  дознании  и  при  наказании - по  спине.  Поэтому,  наверно,  он -  заплечных  дел  мастер. Добавляю  в  ответ  свой  комментарий  к  ответу  МаркИза,  для  большей  ясности  своей  позиции.

Одно из значений выражения за плечами - в прошлом ( у него пять лет службы за плечами ). В прошлом - это позади. А в пространственном значении - это сзади, за спиной, в непосредственной близости ( это ещё одно значение выражения за плечами ). Заплечных дел мастер там и стоял в процессе работы. О фразеологизме "за плечами" см. Фразеологический словарь русского языка. М. 2003. Могло в этом смысле возникнуть выражение "заспинных дел мастер", но возникло и прижилось "заплечных дел".
Слово  мастер  здесь  тоже  не  случайное  -  были  и  мастера  владения  кнутом.

Answer (score 2):

Основной задачей палача была вовсе не казнь, которая на Руси практиковалась сравнительно с Западной Европой нечасто, а пытки, для того чтобы выбить признание.

Одним из наиболее распространённых орудий пытки была дыба. Суть дыбы в том, что жертве медленно растягивают плечевой сустав, вплоть до вывиха. Искусство владения дыбой видимо и послужило поводом для появления выражения.

---

Описание дыбы Григорием Котошихиным XVII век:

> А устроены для всяких воров, пытки: сымут с вора рубашку и руки его **назади** завяжут, подле кисти, верёвкою, обшита та верёвка войлоком, и подымут его к верху, учинено место что и виселица, а ноги его свяжут ремнём; и один человек палач вступит ему в ноги на ремень своею ногою, и тем его отягивает, и у того вора руки станут прямо против головы его, а из суставов выдут вон; и потом сзади палач начнёт бити по спине кнутом изредка...

Т. е. руки **из-за плеч** поднимаются над головой.

Comment: С  первой  частью  согласен.  Но все же  считаю,  что  заплечных  дел  мастер  свои  нехорошие  дела  делал  кнутом  своим  стоя  за  плечами  жертвы,  сзади.  Возможно  этот  термин  относился  именно  к  палачам  мастерски  владеющим  кнутом.  Т.к.  мастерство  и  здесь  требовалось.

Comment: @bernard, сомневаюсь, что подобное наименование давал сам осуждённый, за которым стоял палач, да и про того кто сзади говорят, что он за спиной, а следовательно - "заспинный". Дыба тут подходит в большей степени.

Comment: Непонятна форма "заплечный". При такой этимологии вернее бы было "плечевой!.

Comment: Одно  из  значений  выражения  за  плечами - в  прошлом ( у  него  пять  лет  службы  за  плечами ).  В  прошлом - это  позади.  А  в  пространственном  значении  -  это  сзади, за  спиной,  в  непосредственной  близости ( это  ещё  одно  значение  выражения  за  плечами ). Заплечных дел  мастер  там  и  стоял  в  процессе  работы.  О  фразеологизме  "за  плечами"  см.  Фразеологический  словарь  русского  языка. М. 2003.  Могло  в  этом  смысле  возникнуть  выражение  "заспинных  дел  мастер",  но  возникло  и  прижилось  "заплечных  дел".

Comment: >Одно из значений выражения за плечами ...  
  
Это другая этимология. Я не про неё. 
Врочем, с "прошлым" тоже не согласен - натянутое объяснение.

Comment: Марк Из абсолютно прав . В том словосочетании "мастер заплечных дел" имеется в виду именно ДЫБА . А все остальные комментаторы гонят отсебятину . На той же самой почве , связанной с методами пыток , произошло и выражение  "узнать всю подноготную " : одной из пыток при допросах была пытка с вбиванием иголок под ногти .

Comment: >В том словосочетании "мастер заплечных дел" имеется в виду именно ДЫБА   
  
А какая связь у дыюы с заплечностью?!
Не с плечом как таковым - а с тем, что *за плечами*.

Comment: >А какая связь у дыюы с заплечностью?!

@behemothus, за плечами были у жертвы руки, которые палач поднимал над головой.

Comment: >за плечами были у жертвы руки  
  
Даже если бы они были у палача образование "заплечный" весьма странно.

Answer (score 1):

На Руси пытка дыбой была очень популярна. Она считалась достаточно милосердной, ибо это была не казнь а именно пытка для того, чтобы подозреваемый начал давать показания. И эта пытка делалась не совсем так, как часто показывают в фильмах. Поэтому подозреваемого не калечили и он быстро восстанавливался потом - ведь нужны были здоровые рабочие руки.
Заплечный мастер сначала ВЫКРУЧИВАЛ РУКИ ИЗ ПЛЕЧЕВЫХ СУСТАВОВ. Потом на дыбе растягивали мышцы и связки. БОль была непереносимой. После пытки заплечный мастер опять вставлял руки в плечевые суставы - и человек скоро мог работать.
    Таким образом пытка дыбой была очень эффективной и без серьёзных последствий для здоровья.
Конечно, если подозреваемый вовремя давала показания и пытка останавливалась (связки и мышцы только растягивались, но не рвались).
Со временем и тех, которые пытали по-другому, тоже стали называть заплечными мастерами.
     Если же пытать на дыбе, как показывают в фильмах, то суставы в конечном итоге калечатся и общество получает инвалида.

Comment: Без серьёзных последствий для здоровья? Не совсем так, как часто показывают в фильмах? — Источник знаний про гуманную пытку можете привести?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что все проще.
Не имею возможности копать источники, поэтому - как версия.
"Заплечных дел мастер" - это не палач. Это мастер **тайных** дел. 
Сотрудники всяких охранных и тайных канцелярий - а в более позднее время - всесильные чекисты. Действовали они *за плечами* власти.

Экзекуторские и пыточные функции - следствие такой работы, а не её определение. Хотя в старину оно максимально сближалось.